# How should the community deal with a user who repeats an answer to OP instead of upvoting and accepting my answer?

Tags: discussion

Refer to the question "[How to wait until an element exists with javascript <del>promise</del> ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57391677/1356062).

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57393088/1356062) pointed out that using `MutationObserver` is generally the ideal means to solve the problem in question and additionally provided a sample code that caters to OP's specific use case.

Apparently my answer correctly enabled OP to reach a resolution. However, OP did not *accept* my answer but instead repeated the point I shared earlier in another answer.

OP's attitude breaches the helpful spirit of this community, and if such attitude becomes pervasive then members may become demotivated and less inclined to contribute with their answers.

Comment: Users are not obliged to accept an answer and no-one is going to force to do otherwise. Focus on providing good content, so you gather many upvotes over time. An accept vote is just a an optional; one-time event.

Comment: Users are not obliged to accept an answer indeed. Are they obliged to duplicate one for the same post?

Comment: It is not nice, if that is what you want to hear.

Comment: What I want to discuss is how to manage such antisocial attitude.

Comment: What kind of "solution" do you imagine for something like this? What outcome are you hoping for with this question?

Comment: I would suggest deleting obvious duplicate answers. As this ought to be a discussion, I believe there may be other ideas.

Comment: It's not duplicate as far as the code could reproduce.

Comment: If you want a post deleted, flag it for moderator attention. But a flag on that answer wouldn't fly, it would be declined outright. The answer is not an "obvious duplicate" in any way, and can't be flagged for plagiarism (nor any of the other flag reasons).

Comment: Yours is arguably the _better_ answer, as it provides more of an explanation. But they aren’t duplicates just because they use the same methodology

Answer (score 23):

The self answer of the OP is fine.

They took their own example code they offered in their question and incorporated the suggestions from the other answer. This is fine, as long as it isn't a blatant copy.

I can see why the OP would do this. Your answer generalized the approach of using a Mutation Observer. Which is probably nice for future visitors that stumble on the question and need to solve this in their own context. However, the OP offered two examples (before it was edited) with code and html. That is the question they want to have answered. And they have done so themselves as the current answers seem to be lacking in that respect.

I'm not going into whether this is anti-social or not. If you choose to optimize for future visitors/generalize a solution you run the risk that an answer pops-up that sticks closer to the question asked. It really doesn't matter who posts this answer.

I personally wouldn't be bothered but if you care a friendly comment asking for feedback on your answer could maybe learn you why they opted for sharing what really worked for them. Be careful to not sound passive-aggressive, that often won't end well.